# (Swift Homekit) How to interact with HMAccessory services?

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm trying to write a simple app to control `HomeKit` accessories, and in my code, after writing the code, after adding accessories and services in the `HomeKit` simulator,
when I

```
print(accessory.services.count)
```

I get "0".

Can someone help me with finding the correct way to interact with `HomeKit` accessories?
Say If I create an accessory named "Light", and then add a service named "Lightbulb" in that accessory,
How can I toggle the on and off state of that service?

Thanks.